# isEqualToArray or isEqualToDictionary how deep can it compare?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

Ohkk So I have many scenarios here.

case:1
 A NSArray of dictionaries with a key as type NSString and value also of type NSString.In this case if I change one value in the NSdictionary on the array and try comparing old array with new one it works. isEqualToArray returns false

case:2 
A NSArray of dictionaries with a key type as NSString and value type of some model object with attributes like name,address,DOB . So if I change one value in the model object like name and insert in the dictionary with same key. And compare the arrays with old one still works. isEqualToArray returns false

Now this can go on .What if I have a NSArray in my model object which of again a primitive type of some model.What will happen?? Does isEqualToArray compares almost everything in the values of the objects like deep-serializing compare or it has to stop somewhere??

Comment: `isEqualToArray:` calls `isEqual:` on each object. It doesn't compare the properties by itself. The result entirely depends on how a particular object implements `isEqual:`.

Answer (score 8):

When you compare arrays, the NSArray isEqual: method first checks that both arrays have the same number of elements (otherwise, they are obviously not the same), and then it goes through all the elements one by one and compares them in turn using the isEqual: method. So if your array contains other arrays, or dictionaries, or other objects, then arrays are again compared as just described, dictionaries will be compared as I will describe, and other objects are compared by sending isEqual.

When you compare dictionaries, the NSDictionary isEqual: method first checks both dictionaries have the same number of key/value pairs. Then it takes the first key of the first dictionary, and that key must be present in the second dictionary, and the objects must be the same. Then the second key, the third key and so on.

Comment: This is explaining the "what happens" but not the "How". Who calls who? isEqual: and isEqualToArray:  who calls who, and when?

Answer (score 5):

It all works as long as each class involved has a proper implementation of the `isEqual:` method. It really has nothing to do with `isEqualToArray:`. All that does is call `isEqual:` on each object in the two arrays. So it depends on those objects having a valid `isEqual:` method (and `hash` method).

As long as your model object's `isEqual:` method properly compares each of its properties, you will get the expected result.

Comment: It would be good to point out that this mechanism is recursive, as in each level, objects that are collections, will use the same mechanism (matching number of items, then validating items one by one). This is very powerful/